# Is it safe to use members initialized in the `: , ` portion of a constructor later in `: , `?

Tags: c++, constructor

For example, is it safe to call `Area()` here:

```
Polygon::Polygon( Coord x0, Coord y0, Coord x1, Coord y1 )
    : m_BoundingBox( x0, y0, x1, y1 ), m_Area( m_BoundingBox.Area() )
{
}
```

That is, can one assume that members in the `: ,` portion of a constructor are constructed and initialized in the order they are listed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It depends on the order of the members `m_BoundingBox` and  `m_Area` in the class definition.

The standard states:

> **12.6.2/10** In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the following order:
>
> — First, and only for the constructor of the
>   most derived class (1.8), virtual base classes are initialized in the
>   order they appear on a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the
>   directed acyclic graph of base classes, where “left-to-right” is the
>   order of appearance of the base classes in the derived class
>   base-specifier-list.
>
> — Then, direct base classes are initialized in
>   declaration order as they appear in the base-specifier-list
>   (regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).
>
> — Then, non-static
>   data members are initialized **in the order they were declared in the
>   class definition** (again regardless of the order of the
>   mem-initializers).

So the members are not initialized in the order in which they appear in the mem-initializer, but on their odrer in the class definition.

Here you can see an [online example](http://ideone.com/qWB4yC) of what happens if the elements are in the right or in the wrong order in the class.

Comment: Modern compilers will warn if you put the initializers in a different order

Comment: and, to finish answering OP's question, it is safe to use previously-initialized members in later initializers

Answer (score 3):

Nope, they are initialized in the order in which they are declared in the `class` block. The order in the initialization list has no effect (and that's why many compilers emit a warning when they do not match).